# read csv file and return indented menu c#

Tags: c#, csv, indentation

I have to create an indented navigation menu using below data from a .csv file:

ID;MenuName;ParentID;isHidden;LinkURL
1;Company;NULL;False;/company
2;About Us;1;False;/company/aboutus
3;Mission;1;False;/company/mission
4;Team;2;False;/company/aboutus/team
5;Client 2;10;False;/references/client2
6;Client 1;10;False;/references/client1
7;Client 4;10;True;/references/client4
8;Client 5;10;True;/references/client5
10;References;NULL;False;/references

Using this data I have to develop an application that will parse the file and present the content in a console as the example below:

. Company
.... About Us
....... Team
.... Mission
. References
.... Client 1
.... Client 2

Menu items should be indented (depending on the parent), hidden items (isHidden==true) shouldn't be presented and items should be ordered alphabetically. So far I tried:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"file.csv"))
        {
            // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
            string [] lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(/*';', */'\n');                
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine($"String no {i} is : {lines[i-1]}");
            }                
        }
```

With this i'm getting the lines but I'm stuck after that. I'm new in coding so any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What technology as you using to display your list? Is it a web page? A win forms application?

Comment: This is obviously a homework problem, so I don't want to give you a working answer. I will give you some help though. Try to break down the problem. You need to read in all of the lines and store them in a data structure. Then you can manipulate that data structure to get things in the right order and state. After that you can loop through your data structure to print it back out to the console.

Comment: I am using MS Visual Studio Community 2019 and want to display in console, tnx for your comment

Comment: Wrote code like this 100's of times.  You need to use a recursive menu.  Code is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres some code that should help you get off.

Working sample:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/L37Gjr

It first parses the data to a seperate object. This then gets used to build a m-ary tree, or a hierachical structure of connected nodes. (a node has a reference to 0 or more children).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree

Then tree traversal (use google if you need to know more) is used to insert and print the output, There is still something wrong however. it now uses level order traversal to print, this however comes up with an error:

```
Found root:1 - Company
Found root:10 - References
-------------------
1 - Company
    2 - About Us
    3 - Mission
        4 - Team
10 - References
    6 - Client 1
    5 - Client 2
```

As you can see, it prints `4 - Team` on the wrong level. I'll leave it to you to fix it (because i ran out of time), and if not i hope i gave you plenty ideas to go off and research on your own.

```cs
// sample for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395486/read-csv-file-and-return-indented-menu-c-sharp by sommmen

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data {get;set;}    
        public List<Node<T>> Children { get; set;}

        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node<T>>();
        }

        // Tree traversal in level order
         public List<Node<T>> LevelOrder()
        {
            List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
            Queue<Node<T>> queue = new Queue<Node<T>>();
            queue.Enqueue(this);
            while(queue.Count != 0)
            {               
                Node<T> temp = queue.Dequeue();
                foreach (Node<T> child in temp.Children)
                    queue.Enqueue(child);
                list.Add(temp);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public List<Node<T>> PreOrder()
        {
            List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
            list.Add(this);
            foreach (Node<T> child in Children)
                list.AddRange(child.PreOrder());
            return list;
        }

        public List<Node<T>> PostOrder()
        {
            List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
            foreach (Node<T> child in Children)
                list.AddRange(child.PreOrder());
            list.Add(this);
            return list;
        }


    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public int id   {get;set;}
        public string menuName {get;set;}
        public int? parentID {get;set;}
        public bool isHidden {get;set;}
        public string linkURL  {get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = @"ID;MenuName;ParentID;isHidden;LinkURL
1;Company;NULL;False;/company
2;About Us;1;False;/company/aboutus
3;Mission;1;False;/company/mission
4;Team;2;False;/company/aboutus/team
5;Client 2;10;False;/references/client2
6;Client 1;10;False;/references/client1
7;Client 4;10;True;/references/client4
8;Client 5;10;True;/references/client5
10;References;NULL;False;/references";

        var lines = data.Split('\n');

        var rootNodes = new List<Node<Entity>>();
        var childItems = new List<Entity>();

        // Parse the data to entities
        // Items without a parent are used as rootnodes to build a tree
        foreach(var row in lines.Skip(1))
        {           
            var columns = row.Split(';');

            var id       = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]);
            var menuName = columns[1];
            var parentID = ToNullableInt(columns[2]);
            var isHidden = Convert.ToBoolean(columns[3]);
            var linkURL  = columns[4];

            var entity = new Entity()
                              {
                                id = id,
                                  menuName = menuName,
                                  parentID = parentID,
                                  isHidden = isHidden,
                                  linkURL = linkURL
                              };

            if(parentID == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found root:" + entity.id + " - " + entity.menuName);

                rootNodes.Add(new Node<Entity>()
                              {
                                  Data = entity
                              });
            }
            else
            {
                childItems.Add(entity); 
            }
        }

        // Add the childElements to their appropriate rootnode

        foreach(var rootNode in rootNodes)
        {
            foreach(var childItem in childItems.OrderBy(a=>a.parentID).ThenBy(b=>b.menuName))
            {
                var newNode = new Node<Entity>()
                {
                    Data = childItem
                };

                Insert(rootNode, newNode);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

        foreach(var rootNode in rootNodes)
        {
            var indent = 0;
            var previous = rootNode;
            foreach(var node in rootNode.LevelOrder())
            {
                if(node.Data.isHidden) continue;

                if(previous.Data.parentID != node.Data.parentID)
                    indent++;

                for(var i = 0; i < indent; i++)
                    Console.Write("\t");

                Console.WriteLine(node.Data.id + " - " + node.Data.menuName);
                previous = node;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Insert(Node<Entity> rootNode, Node<Entity> targetNode)
    {
        foreach(var current in rootNode.LevelOrder())
        {
            if(current.Data.id == targetNode.Data.parentID)
            {
                current.Children.Add(targetNode);   
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int? ToNullableInt(string s)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
        return null;
    }
}
```